# Pause carousel slide from going through the next item under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a carousel slide with a couple of questions, if it doesn't meet certain conditions I have to not let the slider go through the next batch of questions

Everytime the person hits the button "submit" it counts how many times has been clicked so each page has a condition, if it doesn't meet the conditions by the next time the user hits submit the counter sets to the point (or item) the user makes the mistake and calls the function again so it starts verifying from the same point, issue is that it blocks the slider perfectly when I make the mistake, but then, in the second attempt, when I do it right then it doesn't let me advance to the next slide, and if I don't make any mistake it's not sending any variable through AJAX (all undefined), curious that with only one question in one slide it worked but it doesn't work with 2 questions, no idea what I'm doing wrong.

SCRIPT

```
function upCount() { 
    if (countClicks == 1){
      var one, prox = false;
      if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
          one = document.getElementById('r1').value;
          prox = true;
          }
      else if (document.getElementById('r2').checked) {
        one = document.getElementById('r2').value;
        prox = true;
        }
      else {
        prox = false;
      }
        if (prox){
        $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("next");
        $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("pause");
        }

        else{
          countClicks--;
          upCount();
        }
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"save.php",
        data: {cont: countClicks,one:one},
        success: function(data){
        }
        });
        } //end of 1


        if (countClicks == 2){
          var r2;
          var r3;
          var prox = false;

      if (document.getElementById('r3').checked || document.getElementById('r4').checked)
       if (document.getElementById('r5').checked || document.getElementById('r6').checked){
        prox = true;
        if (document.getElementById('r3').checked) {
          r2 = document.getElementById('r3').value;
          }
      else if (document.getElementById('r3').checked) {
        r2 = document.getElementById('r4').value;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('r5').checked) {
          r3 = document.getElementById('r5').value;
          prox = true;
          }
      else if (document.getElementById('r6').checked) {
        r3 = document.getElementById('r6').value;
        }
      }

      else{
        prox = false;
      }

      if (prox){
        $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("next");
        countClicks = 2;
        }
      else{
        countClicks = 2;
        $("#carouselExampleControls").carousel("pause");
        upCount();
        }
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"save.php",
        data: {cont: countClicks,r2:r2,r3:r3},
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
        });
        } //end of 2
```

BUTTON (don't think this info is needed, but just in case)

```
  <br></br>
  <div class="container text-center">
  <a onclick="hello(); upCount()" role="button" id= "submit" href="#carouselExampleControls" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="background: #62b539; width:140px; height: 52px;">Continuar</a>
  <br></br>
  </div>
```